# Why get Ubuntu One Music cloud over regular free Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu-one, android, music

Using the Ubuntu One Files application I can download the mp3 files I bought in the Music Store and play them on my Android Phone. So besides the added 15GB storage, what are the advantages of the paid Music Cloud service (and app)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stream online without having to download anything to your phone, thus saving space on the device. Also have your music available from different devices everywhere you go. Quite useful.

Comment: Alright, so it comes down to storage space vs. data plan? With my current SD card storage and the slow mobile network data connection in my plan I would prefer to just download them once. Thanks for clarifying anyway.